# Regex To Catch Two Different Scenarios

Tags: regex

Goal: Trying to capture just the **Total Number** (95,600.91) however on some documents it shows with no spaces and need to create regex that looks for scenario with spaces and scenario with no spaces but returns 1 capture group.

Total Sample I: ========================================== 95,600.91 .00 95,600.91

Total Sample II: ========================================== 95,600.91.0095,600.91

My Regex For The Total: `(?:==\s+\d.*?\.00)(\S+)|(?:==\s+\d.*?\.00\s+)(\S+)`

Sample Text:

```
DM20066906 2020-06-22 WHOLE FOODS-WEST       12.37-    .00   12.37- 
DM20067812 2020-06-22 WHOLE FOODS-WEST       132.26-   .00   132.26-
DM20068372 2020-06-12 POMME D'API            143.72-   .00   143.72-
DM20069488 2020-06-25 WHOLE FOODS EAST       3.75-     .00   3.75-  
DM20069594 2020-06-12 J HOLTMANN             367.50-   .00   367.50-
DM20069986 2020-06-10 GOOD N NATURAL         210.00-   .00   210.00-
DM20079015 2020-07-03 VPFP PROGRAM FEES      641.32-   .00   641.32-

========================================== 95,600.91 .00 95,600.91

Printed on 2020-07-07 at 12:49
```

Comment: Like `==\s+\d.*?\.00\s*(\S+)`?

Comment: Is your data fixed length records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying making the whitespace after `.00` optional with `\s*`

```
(?:==\s+\d.*?\.00)\s*(\S+)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Looks like the \s* was what I was missing in my regex. My understanding is the \s* must mean the space is allowed but not necessary right?

Comment: yes. The `\s*` can be read as "a whitespace character repeated 0 to many times"